# Loading multiple families of fonts from google fonts while using '&text' is not working

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api, google-fonts

I'm building a font picker, and per the google fonts documentation, it says to append multiple families as such: ?family=Roboto&family=Karla etc. That works fine. When I start trying to load individual characters of the font though, used for previews in the font picker, it stops loading any of the fonts except for the first font listed.

For example:
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla&text=Karla&family=Heebo&text=Heebo

If I only try it on one font, such as ?family=Karla&text=Karla, that works, only loading the Karla characters, but once I try to do multiple families, it doesn't work. Am I doing this properly?

Comment: You're making us guess. Please post some [reprex]...

Comment: Good point. I'll make a code snippet.